# How to change color of points and lines in the given code?

Tags: plotting, color

Using this code

```
data = Table[{n, Sin[2 n]/n}, {n, 1, 100}];
ListLogPlot[data, 
  Joined -> True, 
  Mesh -> All, 
  PlotMarkers -> {"•", 9}, 
  PlotStyle -> Thickness[0], 
  BaseStyle -> 10]
```

I get

[image]

How can I control and change the color of points and lines? For example, how can I have black points with gray lines? or any other colors.

Comment: Look at the linear plot instead of log, it has negative values (below the x-axis) `ListPlot[data, Mesh -> All, Joined -> True]`  which cannot be represented on a log plot like this. That explains the gaps.

Comment: To get different colours, use `PlotStyle`, or interleave the colours in the data for instance: `ListPlot[Style[#, RandomColor[]] & /@ data, Mesh -> All, Joined -> True, PlotStyle->Red]`

Comment: Your question is too broad. Please be more specific about what coloring you want.

Comment: @m_goldberg For example, how can I have black points with gray joined lines, instead of the blue ones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**

We can also remove the `Mesh->All` and Add the `Style` to `PlotMarkers`

```
data = Table[{n, Sin[2 n]/n}, {n, 1, 100}];
ListPlot[data, Joined -> True, 
 PlotMarkers -> Style["\[Bullet]", 12, Red], 
 PlotStyle -> Directive[Gray, Thickness[0]], BaseStyle -> 10, 
 ClippingStyle -> False]
```

**Original**

For example,change the `MeshStyle` to `Red`

```
data = Table[{n, Sin[2 n]/n}, {n, 1, 100}];
ListPlot[data, Joined -> True, 
 Mesh -> All,MeshStyle -> Red,
 PlotStyle -> Directive[Blue, Thickness[Tiny]],  
 ClippingStyle -> False]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this will work for you.

```
ListLogPlot[Abs@data,
 Joined -> True,
 PlotRange -> All,
 AspectRatio -> 1,
 Frame -> True,
 PlotMarkers -> Style["•", 20, Black],
 PlotStyle -> {Thin, Red},
 BaseStyle -> 10]
```

[image: plot]

I plotted the absolute values of your data and changed the color of the joining lines to red to get a plot that better illustrates the color control options that I am recommending.